# Should I check all possible paths when looking for an installed package in a deployment script?

Tags: linux, postgresql, deployment, devops

I am creating a deployment script for my webapp.

The app is dependent on some packages in the system, e.g. postgres.

Currently I am using code like this:

```
if ! [ -x "$(command -v psql)" ]; then
   echo 'psql is not installed.' >&2
   sh ./install_postgres.sh
fi
```

Though, I cannot be sure that if it's not on the path, then it's not installed. Probably, the package is located somewhere but not exposed in the PATH.

So, should I look into folders and try to find the package I need or is looking in the PATH enough to know if it's installed the standard way or not?

Comment: try `locate psql` if it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should take a different approach.

### The way that I recommend, and have done for years

- Build your application using the distro's standard package maintenance tools (RPM/DEB).
- Your application should then lay out its dependencies in the building of the package.
- Upon installation of your package, the dependencies will also be installed.
- Use CM (Chef, Ansible) to install the package.

### This way has the following benefits

- Reusable.
- Can roll-back; if you properly version your builds.
- Fully automatable; you can build the packages with Jenkins or regular bash.

### There is also another way

- Use a CM (Chef, Ansible); and then have it install the dependencies, and then your application.

I do not recommend the latter way because you lose the ability to rollback; which we all know is bad for production.